# @font face - Font behaviour different between local and live server

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I am beginner in a coding world and asking the first question in here, hope I will explain myself correctly!

I have uploaded Proxima Nova Regular and Open Sans Light via font face and included below styling in my css file. Both fonts work, but not the way they should be. Proxima Nova renders with much more weight on, in comparison to the one installed on my computer. Also both fonts don't pick up html bolding feature? to make text bold I need to specify font weight in css file, there is no other way? Not sure what the problem is. I have tried to find a solution but couldn't find any. Maybe it is something really basic that I haven't been able to grasp yet during my learning journey.
I have downloaded fonts with the Font Squirrel. 
Fonts are based in a separate assets folder to my css file. 
I have tried to clear my font cache multiple times and it didn't help. 
I am working with Chrome however have the same issue with other browsers: Mozilla and IE.

This is a font I am after and I had it working on my pc, having proxima nova and open sans installed locally: https://www.katietreggiden.com/about

this is what i get via font face and web server: https://youmedigital.com/

Thank you for your help in advance:-)

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Proxima Nova";
src: local("Proxima Nova");
src: url("assets/fonts/Proxima Nova.woff") format("woff"),
     url("assets/fonts/Proxima Nova.woff2") format("woff2"),
     url("assets/fonts/Proxima Nova.ttf") format("truetype");
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Open Sans";
src: local("Open Sans");
src: url("assets/fonts/Open Sans Light.woff") format("woff"),
     url("assets/fonts/Open Sans Light.woff2") format("woff2"),
     url("assets/fonts/Open Sans Light.ttf") format("truetype");
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
}

body {
font-family: "Proxima Nova"; 
font-weight: 300;
color: #575757;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
font-family: "Open Sans";
font-weight: 300;
color: #000000;
```

}

Comment: The font type for your computer and for the web is different. You maybe use desktop font for the web. You need to get the Proxima Nova and Open Sans web font.

Comment: Hi Seno, I have used webfonts, uploaded ttf to Font Squirrel and generated woff files which I have added then to my directory, unless there is another step that I am missing here? thanks

Comment: Hey Kris, I see. Would you be able to get it the proper web font without converting it on Font Squirrel?